# Runtime error -2147417848 (80010108) method 'add' of object 'listRows' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I went through forum. But nothing works for me. I use the user form to insert the data to table, but after 1st succesfull sometimes even more data inputs, the run time error occure Add of object listRows failed. I identified, that when I disable the `.lstData.RowSource = "tblErrorData"`, from Reset() macro, everything works fine, but when I try to disable it by inserting `form.lstData.RowSource = ""` before  `Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Addt`, it doesnt work. I think I am missing something.

```
Sub Reset()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim shCust As Worksheet, shDpt As Worksheet, shErr As Worksheet
    
    ' Clear form controls and fill comboboxes
    For Each form In Array(frmErrorForm, frmErrorFormCZ)
        With form
            .lstData.RowSource = ""
        
            .cmbCustomer.Clear
            Set shCust = Sheets("Customers")
            For i = 2 To shCust.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(shCust.Range("A2:A" & i), shCust.Cells(i, 1)) = 1 Then
                    .cmbCustomer.AddItem shCust.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
            
            .cmbDepartment.Clear
            Set shDpt = Sheets("Departments")
            For i = 2 To shDpt.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(shDpt.Range("A2:A" & i), shDpt.Cells(i, 1)) = 1 Then
                    .cmbDepartment.AddItem shDpt.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
            
            .cmbErrorType.Clear
            Set shErr = Sheets("Errors")
            If .Name = "frmErrorForm" Then
                For i = 2 To shErr.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(shErr.Range("A2:A" & i), shErr.Cells(i, 1)) = 1 Then
                        .cmbErrorType.AddItem shErr.Cells(i, 1)
                    End If
                Next i
            ElseIf .Name = "frmErrorFormCZ" Then
                For i = 2 To shErr.Range("E10000").End(xlUp).Row
                    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(shErr.Range("E2:E" & i), shErr.Cells(i, 5)) = 1 Then
                        .cmbErrorType.AddItem shErr.Cells(i, 5)
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
            
            .cmbErrorDescription.Clear
            .cmbErrorDetail.Clear
            
            .txtAffectedKits.Value = ""
            .txtComments.Value = ""
            .txtOrder.Value = ""
            
            For j = 1 To 10
                .Controls("txtEmployee" & j).Value = ""
            Next j
            
            'Data preview in listbox
            .lstData.RowSource = "tblErrorData"
            .lstData.ColumnCount = 28
            .lstData.ColumnHeads = True
            .lstData.ColumnWidths = "0;65;65;45;60;60;50;95;60;55;70;0;70;0;65;0;65;0;65;0;65;0;65;0;65;0;65;0;65"
            .lstData.TopIndex = .lstData.ListCount - 1 ' Scroll to last entered data
            
            .txtOrder.SetFocus
            
        End With
    Next form
End Sub

Sub TransferDataFromFormToTable(form As Object)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newRow As ListRow
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set tbl = sh.ListObjects("tblErrorData")
    
    form.lstData.RowSource = ""
    
    ' Unprotect the worksheet
    UnprotectSheet sh
       
    ' Add a new row below the last row
    Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    
    ' Transfer data from the form to the table
    With newRow
        .Range(1) = tbl.ListRows.Count - 1 ' Auto-incrementing ID
        .Range(2) = Now()
        .Range(3) = Application.UserName
        .Range(4) = form.cmbCustomer.Value
        .Range(5) = form.txtOrder.Value
        .Range(6) = form.cmbDepartment.Value
        
        ' Check if the Czech form is used, and perform the language conversion
        If TypeName(form) = "frmErrorFormCZ" Then
            Dim shErrors As Worksheet
            Dim errorType As Variant, errorDesc As Variant, errorDetail As Variant
            
            Set shErrors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Errors")
               
            errorType = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(shErrors.Range("A:A"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(form.cmbErrorType.Value, shErrors.Range("E:E"), 0)) ' Language conversion for Error Type
            errorDesc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(shErrors.Range("B:B"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(form.cmbErrorDescription.Value, shErrors.Range("F:F"), 0)) ' Language conversion for Error Description
            errorDetail = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(shErrors.Range("C:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(form.cmbErrorDetail.Value, shErrors.Range("G:G"), 0)) ' Language conversion for Error Detail
            
            If Not IsError(errorType) Then .Range(7) = errorType
            If Not IsError(errorDesc) Then .Range(8) = errorDesc
            If Not IsError(errorType) Then .Range(9) = errorDetail
        Else
            .Range(7) = form.cmbErrorType.Value
            .Range(8) = form.cmbErrorDescription.Value
            .Range(9) = form.cmbErrorDetail.Value
        End If
        
        .Range(10) = form.txtAffectedKits.Value
        .Range(31) = form.txtComments.Value
    
        'Set link for external file as String
        Dim sourceFile As String
        Dim lookupColumn As String
        Dim returnColumn As String

        sourceFile = Sheets("Sources").Range("B1").Value
        lookupColumn = Sheets("Sources").Range("B2").Value
        returnColumn = Sheets("Sources").Range("B3").Value

        ' Loop through txtEmployee controls and set formulas
    Dim employeeIndex As Integer
    For employeeIndex = 1 To 10
        Dim txtEmployee As Control
        Set txtEmployee = form.Controls("txtEmployee" & employeeIndex)
        
        If Len(txtEmployee.Value) > 0 Then
            ' Insert the employee value into the corresponding column
            .Range(12 + (employeeIndex - 1) * 2).Value = txtEmployee.Value
            Dim lookupValueColumn As Long
            lookupValueColumn = 11 + (employeeIndex - 1) * 2
            .Range(lookupValueColumn).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" & .Range(12 + (employeeIndex - 1) * 2).Address(False, False) & ", '" & sourceFile & "'!" & lookupColumn & ", '" & sourceFile & "'!" & returnColumn & ",, 0)"
        End If
    Next employeeIndex
               
'        Dim rngCheck As Range
'        Set rngCheck = sh.Range(sh.Cells(iRow, 10), .Cells(iRow, 28))
'
        ' Display warning message when incorrect initials are entered and function cant match with name
'        For Each cell In rngCheck
'            If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
'                If TypeName(form) = "frmErrorForm" Then
'                MsgBox "One or more fields are not filled correctly. Please contact the supervisor for correction.", vbExclamation, "Error"
'                Else
'                MsgBox "Jedno nebo více polí není vyplněno správně. Obraťte se prosím na nadřízeného, aby provedl opravu.", vbExclamation, "Error" 'msg for czech version
'                End If
'                Exit Sub
'            End If
'        Next cell

        ' Display success message
        If TypeName(form) = "frmErrorForm" Then
        MsgBox "Data submitted successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
        Else
        MsgBox "Data byla úspěšně odeslána", vbInformation, "Success" 'msg for czech version
        End If
        
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    ' Protect the worksheet again with desired settings
    ProtectSheet sh
    
End Sub

Sub ProtectSheet(sh As Worksheet) ' Function to protect the sheet with desired settings
    sh.Protect AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

Sub UnprotectSheet(sh As Worksheet) ' Function to unprotect the sheet
    sh.Unprotect
End Sub

Sub Submit()
    ' Call the common data transfer subroutine for the respective form
    If frmErrorForm.Visible Then
        TransferDataFromFormToTable frmErrorForm
    ElseIf frmErrorFormCZ.Visible Then
        TransferDataFromFormToTable frmErrorFormCZ
    Else
        ' Handle the case when neither form is visible (optional)
        MsgBox "No form is active.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Sub Show_Form()

    frmErrorForm.Show

End Sub

Sub Show_FormCZ()

    frmErrorFormCZ.Show

End Sub

Sub Show_LanguageSelection()
    
    frmLanguageSelection.Show

End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: Put [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables. See if that changes anything.